# How to combine columns from a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name_1': ['Juan', '', ''],
    'name_2': ['', 'Pedro', ''],
    'name_3': ['', '', 'Ana'],
    'l_name': ['García', 'Sánchez', 'Hernández'],
    'profession_4': ['Doctor', 'Doctor', ''], 
    'profession_5': ['', '', 'architect'],
    'hobbie_6': ['Dance', '', 'Music'],
    'hobbie_7': ['', 'Music', 'Paint'],
    'hobbie_8': ['', '', 'Dance'],
})
df
```

[image]

Which has columns with the same names, so what I want to do is combine all those repeated columns and create only one and it looks like this:

[image]

For that, generate the following code:

```
# Group the columns by their name before the underscore
grouped_columns = df.columns.to_series().groupby(lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[0]).apply(list).tolist()

# Iterate through each group of columns and combine them
for columns in grouped_columns:
    # Get the name of the group
    group_name = columns[0].rsplit('_', 1)[0]
    # Combine the columns into a new column with the name of the group
    df[group_name + '_combined'] = pd.concat([df[column] for column in columns], axis=1).apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
    
# Drop the original columns
df.drop(df.filter(regex='_\d+$').columns, axis=1, inplace=True)

# Display the resulting DataFrame
df
```

But I got this table, which prints me out of order and also where there is no data it puts /
[image]

How could I improve my code so that it prints the table in order and without the unnecessary /, that is, if there is an empty cell that needs to be combined with a full one, that in the new column there is only the existing value and not the value / of the empty?

Answer (score 4):

You can standardize your column names removing the suffix (with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)), then perform a [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) on the columns:

```
(df.groupby(df.columns.str.replace(r'_\d+$', '', regex=True), axis=1, sort=False)
   .agg(lambda g: g.apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x[x.ne('')]), axis=1))
)
```

Or:

```
(df.set_axis(df.columns.str.replace(r'_\d+$', '', regex=True), axis=1)
   .replace('', np.nan).stack()
   .groupby(level=[0,1], sort=False).agg('/'.join)
   .unstack()
)
```

Output:

```
    name     l_name profession             hobbie
0   Juan     García     Doctor              Dance
1  Pedro    Sánchez     Doctor              Music
2    Ana  Hernández  architect  Music/Paint/Dance
```

Comment: Thank you!, but in case I have some columns with numerical values, what would you suggest?

Comment: What would you want to do? Concatenate (replace `'/'.join` with `lambda x: '/'.join(map(str, x))`)? Sum?

Comment: this way?

(df.groupby(df.columns.str.replace(r'_\d+$', '', regex=True), axis=1, sort=False)
   .agg(lambda g: g.apply(lambda x: lambda x: '/'.join(map(str, x))))
)

Comment: No, a single `lambda`: `g.apply(lambda x: '/'.join(map(str, x)))`, or for the second approach: `groupby(level=[0,1], sort=False).agg(lambda x: '/'.join(map(str, x)))`

Answer (score 1):

Another option with groupby (mozway's route is shorter, and should be more performant):

```py
(df
.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis = 1)
.agg(lambda f: f.iloc[:, 0].str.cat(f.iloc[:, 1:], sep = '/').str.strip('/'))
.rename(columns = lambda col: f"{col}_combined" if not col == "l" else f"{col}_name")
)
     hobbie_combined     l_name name_combined profession_combined
0              Dance     García          Juan              Doctor
1              Music    Sánchez         Pedro              Doctor
2  Music/Paint/Dance  Hernández           Ana           architect
```

Since this is essentially a string concatenation, you might get more performance with a for loop:

```py
out = df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis = 1)
contents = {}

for key, frame in out:
    value = frame.apply("/".join, axis = 1).str.strip("/")
    if key == 'l':
        contents["l_name"] = value
    else:
        contents[f"{key}_combined"] = value
pd.DataFrame(contents)
     hobbie_combined     l_name name_combined profession_combined
0              Dance     García          Juan              Doctor
1              Music    Sánchez         Pedro              Doctor
2  Music/Paint/Dance  Hernández           Ana           architect
```

You can dump down further within the `apply` space to plain python - optimise only if needed.

YOu could also go the route of a MultiIndex and a for loop

Comment: Thank you!, but in case I have some columns with numerical values, what would you suggest?

Comment: an example of such columns would be helpful, ,with the expected output

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
out = df.replace('', pd.NA).bfill(axis=1)
out = pd.concat([
    out['name_1'], out['l_name'], out['profession_4'],
    out.filter(like='hobbie_').apply(
        lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna().drop_duplicates()), axis=1)], axis=1)
out.columns = ['name_combined', 'l_name', 'profession_combined', 'hobbie_combined']
```

---

Another possible solution:

```
(df.assign(id = df.index).melt('id')
 .mask(lambda x: x['value'].eq('')).dropna()
 .assign(variable = lambda x: x['variable']
         .str.replace(r'_\d', '_combined', regex=True))
 .pivot_table(index='id', columns='variable', 
              values='value', aggfunc=lambda x: '/'.join(x), sort=False)
 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

Output:

```
variable name_combined     l_name profession_combined    hobbie_combined
0                 Juan     García              Doctor              Dance
1                Pedro    Sánchez              Doctor              Music
2                  Ana  Hernández           architect  Music/Paint/Dance
```

Comment: melt plus pivot looks expensive (although if the data size is relatively small, it doesn't matter)

Comment: Thanks, @sammywemmy, for having commented my solution and for having pointed out that.